# Pass parameters from batch file to a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file that is supposed to execute a `powershell` script and I also want pass a file path to the script out of the batch file. The file path should then be inserted at a certain point in the script.

```
$Berechtigung = Get-ACL -Path "C:\_TEST\TEST.txt"
```

do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything you have tried?  You should be able to create a parameter in the powershell script using `param()` and then pass your batch variable to the powershell script as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From a batch file (`cmd.exe`), you must call the Windows PowerShell CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), in order to execute a PowerShell script (`.ps1`), optionally with arguments, via the `-File` parameter.
- In your PowerShell script, you can refer to arguments passed by the caller:

  - either: purely *positionally*, via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args), where `$args[0]` contains the first argument, `$args[1]` the second, and so on.
  - or: via *declared parameters*, such as `param([string] $Path)` - see the relevant section of the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) help topic.

---

Therefore:

Assuming your PowerShell script is named `foo.ps1` and contains the following content:

```bash
# Content of foo.ps1

param([string] $Path)  # Declare a string parameter named -Path

$Berechtigung = Get-ACL -Path $Path
```

You can then call this script from your batch file as follows (this assumes that `foo.ps1` is located in the current directory - adjust as needed):

```bash
@echo off

:: ...

powershell.exe -NoProfile -File .\foo.ps1 "C:\_TEST\TEST.txt"
```

Note that if you declare parameters (with `param(...)`) you can also pass your arguments as *named* ones, namely by placing the target parameter name before an argument:

```bash
:: Note the -Path before the file path.
:: Only works if you have declared this parameter via param(...)
powershell.exe -NoProfile -File .\foo.ps1 -Path "C:\_TEST\TEST.txt"
```